# What happens to my local code when I use git pull/fetch/merge commands

Tags: git

I have a hard time understanding the documentation, so I am asking this question as simple as I can.

This is the code on my local:

```
line1: A 
line2: B   
line3: C  
line4: (empty)   
line5: D   
line6: E
```

This is the code on repository:

```
line1: A   
line2: B  
line3: C   
line4: F 
line5: G  
line6: E
```

What happens when I do `pull`, `fetch` and `merge`?

Comment: You can easily try it. You'll have have conflicts that you'll need to resolve.

Comment: How can I try it? (My question had bad format, edited it now)

Comment: Create a repository, push a file with the desired content, change it, pull, fetch and merge.

Answer (score 0):

fetch - nothing happen to the working folder. This is operation on git tree only.

pull - is "fetch and rebase" or "fetch and merge" - your local file may be modified, which may cause conflict.

merge - not applicable with terms "remote" you can merge code from 2 branches in git tree, resulting combination of code from one branch with code in another.